# What can i do to make PHP mail() working

Tags: php, email

When i use `mail()` function it doesn't work. What should i edit to get it working.
I tried multiple combinations of code like

```
<?php
$to = "myemail";
$subject = "My subject";
$txt = "Hello world!";
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com" . "\r\n" .
"CC: somebodyelse@example.com";

mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
?>
```

And nothing comes even to spam folder.

Comment: You should use SwiftMailer instead.

Comment: Share the errors please ...

Comment: No errors in output, just blank page. The page is loading for about 1min and then blank page.

Comment: You have a functional webserver at localhost installed?

Comment: @djay Server is on Microsoft Windows Server 2003R2 and as i can see this SwiftMailer plugin is for linux

Comment: are you working on localhost?

Comment: If your system/server not configured SMTP then it ll not work...

Comment: How to check if server has configured SMTP ? Via phpinfo() ?

Comment: Check the error log on your webhost or localhost and see if it turns anything up

Comment: There are two possibilties. 1. Using localhost and let the settings and install a local SMTP Server for example Mercury Mail 2. Using an external SMTP Server (e.g. gmail). Then you should switch to the wonderful PHPMailer class - which has wonderful support for smtp (with ssl), and many functions like attachment, html-mail, etc...

Comment: check your php.ini file for [mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost

if smtp=localhost is set then it won't work

Comment: SMTP server response in log is 550 5.7.1

Comment: PHP mailers is a library. Its a number of classes written for you. Just include and use it. http://swiftmailer.org

Answer (score 0):

You should add this in your code

```
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$headers .= "From: <".$from. ">" ;
```

Hope this will work

Comment: \r\n is windows  line break style, unix is \n. Assuming this PHP  is running on linux.

Comment: @enapupe I don't get any error using this code, i run this code on windows and in Linux on both os

Comment: Sure it works. But you should use PHP_EOL constant, it is more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending email without passing any header information.
Just use **to**, **subject** and **body** variables.

Comment: let me know what happens then.

Comment: Tried that too, still doesn't work. I suppose there is no support enabled for sending email on my server

Comment: But in phpinfo() there is : Internal Sendmail Support for Windows enabled

Comment: yes i do, shall i upload ini file to some webhost ?

Comment: I tried your script by uploading at http://confesstalk.com/cl/test.php and it is working perfectly..
Use this:
$headers .= 'From: Domain <info@domain.com>' . "\r\n";
instead of:
$headers .= 'From: domain' . "\r\n";

Comment: Is your server running linux or Windows Server, because i think that windows server could be the problem

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php

$regDate = "2013-02-14";
$today = date("Y-m-d");

$date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+1 year", strtotime($regDate)));

if($today == $date)
    {
$to = "email";
$subject = "My subject";
$txt = "anything";
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com" . "\r\n" .
"CC: somebodyelse@example.com";
mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
}
else
    {
echo"no";
}
?>
```

Comment: nope, still no errors, only in php.log SMTP response 550 5.7.1